# What will be the map induced by the inclusion on the homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $\ i : \mathbb CP^n \longrightarrow \mathbb C P^{n+k}$ be the standard inclusion. Then how do I figure out $i_* :  H_{m} (\mathbb C P^n) \longrightarrow H_{m} (\mathbb C P^{n+k})$ where $2 \leq m \leq 2n$ and $m$ is even?

Could anybody give me some suggestion on it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you know to calculate the homology of $\mathbb{CP}^n$?

Comment: Yes I know using Mayer-Vietoris sequence @Arctic Char. I know that the homology groups are $\mathbb Z$ at every even degree upto twice the dimension of the space.

Comment: ok... So how do you use Mayer-Vietoris sequence to find the homology of $\mathbb{CP}^n$? The point is, if you know the generators of $H_*(\mathbb{CP}^k)$, then it is pretty easy to find what is $i_*$.

Comment: Do you mean cellular homology of $\mathbb C P^n$ @Arctic Char?

Comment: Well, even better if you know cellular homology.

Comment: Yes I know cellular homology @Arctic Char.

Comment: It's very easy to compute the cellular homology of $\mathbb C P^n$ @Arctic Char because the differentials are all $0.$

Comment: @Arctic Char will it be an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ admits a CW-complex structure, so that the inclusion $\mathbb{CP}^n \to \mathbb{CP}^{n+k}$ preserves the structure. Thus we think of the inclusion as the inclusion of a sub-complex $X_{2n} = \mathbb{CP}^n$ into $X =\mathbb{CP}^{n+k} = X_{2(n+k)}$. It suffices to check for $k=1$; the general case can be done by the compostion of inclusions
$$ X_{2n} \to X_{2n+2} \to \cdots \to X_{2(n+k)}.$$

The long exact sequence on relative homology of the pair $(X_{2n}, X_{2n+2})$ gives

$$\cdots \to H_{m+1}(X_{2n+2}, X_{2n}) \to H_m(X_{2n})\overset{i_*}{\to } H_m(X_{2n+2}) \to H_m (X_{2n+2}, X_{2n}) \to \cdots .$$

Given that $m\le 2n$, $m+1 <2n+2$. Since

\begin{align}
H_{k}(X_{2n+2}, X_{2n}) &\cong \widetilde H_k (X_{2n+2}/X_{2n}) \cong \widetilde H_k (\mathbb S^{2n+2}), \end{align}

$H_{k}(X_{2n+2}, X_{2n}) = 0$ for all $k<2n+2$. Thus $i_*$ is an isomorphism for all $m \le 2n$.

Everything can be found in Chapter 2 of Hatcher.

Comment: So similar thing is true for $\mathbb R P^n$ also. Am I right? Since $\mathbb R P^{n+1}/\mathbb R P^n \approx S^{n+1}.$

Comment: Yes only when $m < n$, when $m=n$, $m+1 = n+1$ and thus $H_{n+1} (\mathbb {RP}^{n+1}, \mathbb{RP}^n)$ is non-zero. The same argument here shows that $i_*: H_m(X_k)\to H_m(X)$ is an isomorphism when $m <k$ and is surjective when $m=k$. @AntonioClaire

Comment: what will be the homology of $\mathbb C P^{n+k}/\mathbb C P^n.$ I find that all the reduced homology groups are all $0$ upto $2n.$ Is it true?

Comment: $\mathbb{CP}^{n+1} /\mathbb{CP}^n \cong \mathbb S^{2n+2}$, so all reduced homology is zero except at $2n+2$. @AntonioClaire

Comment: No I take $\mathbb C P^{n+k}/\mathbb C P^n.$ I think for that the reduced homology groups are all zero except for $2n + 2 \leq m \leq 2n + 2k$ and $m$ even in which cases the homology groups are all $\mathbb Z.$ This coincides with your conclusion when $k = 1.$

Comment: But the computation of $\mathbb R P^{n+k} / \mathbb R P^n$ is cumbersome. We need to break it up into $4$ cases where $n$ and $k$ are even or odd.

Comment: If you use cellular homology, the first cell attached to $\mathbb{CP}^{n+k}/\mathbb{CP}^n$ (besides the zero-dimensional one) is of dimension $\mathbb S^{2n+2}$, thus you are right. @AntonioClaire